# Identifying this part - ALPS 242N Probably a rotary encoder

Tags: identification, encoder, rotary

This was damaged in shipping.  Looking it over I THINK it's a rotary encoder.
ALPS seems to have forgotten they ever made the part.  Printed on the back is ALPS 242N.  Can't find any specs on it.

[image: all together now]

[image: inside of knob mount]

[image: inside of knob]

[image: underside of knob ALPS 242N]

UPDATE --
Picked up an ALPS EC12E2420801 (24 Res, 24 Detent).  Wrong part...
Need to measure all the dimensions first next time.  The original part is 16mm wide, the EC12 is <13mm.  Had to go searching through mouser data sheets to find one with the correct dimensions.  Waiting for [the new one](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/PEC16-4220F-N0024/?qs=%2Fha2pyFadugqRPNEprXemiAnzxSGS6c9TCLcTN%2FyrUoMj%252bDYswtJNw%3D%3D) to show up but it looks like it should work.

Final Update -- Finished!  Picked up a Bournes PEC16-4220F-N0024 (24 PPR, 24 Detent) and it works perfectly.  I don't know if the original had detent or not, but I like the feel of it.

Comment: tell the shipper.  (lol) poor packing material. It's an "incremental type" 2phase 24 pole rotary encoder . without? detent

Comment: Alps won't want to talk to you directly unless you are an OEM. If you try to sub there is some chance the encoder will fit and have close enough the number of pulses but may work backwards (in which case you could hack and swap the two outer pins A and B.

Comment: Someone from ALPS did respond to an inquiry but couldn't find a reference to that part themselves.  They were suggesting their potentiometers, which I was pretty sure was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a rotary encoder - looks to be a conductive 24 PPR variety.

Answer (score 2):

It's a rotary encoder for sure. Unless the part number is written on the board / part, you will have big difficulty to find it. I recommend you to email the manufacturer to have more information about that part. As long as you explain your situation : that the board has been damage during the delivery (with picture), they will either give you the part number or change the board for a new one.

Comment: Old hardware from an auction.  There isn't the possibility of sending it back.

Comment: You can remplace it with another rotary encoder. As long the new part have the same step as the old one, it will work.

Comment: Exactly why I'm asking what this specific part is (or equivalent).

Comment: How many steps have the previous encoder ?

Answer (score 1):

probably that is the [EC12](http://www.alps.com/prod/info/E/HTML/Encoder/Incremental/EC12E/EC12E_list.html) Series from ALPS

Comment: From the comments I would say a 24 PPR with Bushing Type, without detent (though with detent would probably work just fine as well).  I'll have to measure it later to get the exact possible replacement.

Comment: sadly, not an EC12